# How do I compute the luminance of a pixel?

Tags: graphics

I have a color (say $R=100, G=150, B=130$). How do I compute its intensity?

Do I just sum up all three components? Or are the colors not evenly weighted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The colors are not evenly interpreted by our eyes.  When I want to make a picture gray scale, I usually go for the following calculation of the luminance of a pixel.

```
luminance = (r * 0.3) + (g * 0.59) + (b * 0.11)
```

Read more in the [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) question [Formula to determine brightness of RGB color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-brightness-of-rgb-color).

Comment: For additional context, this is the Y,  in the YIQ color space http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YIQ